# Phonegap and Windows Phone 7: IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: windows-phone-8, cordova

I am having issues moving a phonegap application from Android and iOS to WP8. It seems to be crashing when I try to load some language .JSON files. The versions that I use are phonegap 2.9.0 and jQuery 2.0.3. Everything is working as intended on Android and iOS.

Console output:

```
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Runtime.Serialization.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Updating IsolatedStorage for APP:DeviceID :: ********-****-****-****-***********
CordovaBrowser_Navigated :: www/index.html
CommandString : Device/getDeviceInfo/Device899915039/[]
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded         'C:\windows\system32\System.ServiceModel.Web.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\en-US\mscorlib.debug.resources.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
CommandString : NetworkStatus/getConnectionInfo/NetworkStatus899915040/[]
An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
The thread 0x1160 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x80c has exited with code 259 (0x103).
CommandString : DebugConsole/log/DebugConsole899915041/"Received Event: deviceready"
Log:["Received Event: deviceready","DebugConsole899915041"]
The thread 0x8c8 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
CommandString : File/readResourceAsText/File899915042/["localization/nb-NO.json"]
A first chance exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in no.visma.patentstyret.DLL
An exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in no.visma.patentstyret.DLL but was not handled in user code
```

This is the ajax loading of the language files:

```
 var _loadDataSet = function(callback) {
        $.ajax({url: "localization/" + _language + ".json", async: false, dataType: 'json', success: function(data) {
            _dataSet = data;
            if(callback) {
                callback();
            }
        }}).error(function(e) {
            console.error("Error in language files.");
            console.error(e);
        });
    };
```

I have no idea where to start, any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Updated my answer again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show please your reading from file code.

I was making application with mustache templating engine, and did this:

```
$.Mustache.load("./templates/about/about-app.tpl")
```

This didn't load because WP8 requres full path:

```
$.Mustache.load("www/templates/about/about-app.tpl")
```

By the way, WP7 - doesn't load with full path, only with relative =)))

**And another thing:**

```
$.ajax({url: "www/localization/" + _language + ".json", async: false, dataType: 'json', success: function(data) {
```

WP projects don't like extensions like json and others ( sometimes it did work, sometimes didn't NO IDEA WHY ), so i suggest you do:

1) Change file type to *.txt

2) Request:

```
$.ajax({url: "www/localization/" + _language + ".txt", async: false, dataType: 'text', success: function(data) {
```

**UPDATE:**

Almost forgot, to use AJAX you must do this:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
    jQuery.support.cors = true;
    $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
}, false);
```

Comment: Tried renaming the file to .txt, unfortunally no change. Also checked with an earlier version of jquery with no success.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use XMLHttpRequest. Tested and works on Android, iPhone and Windows Phone 8. While the solution for loading the local language files was to add the data to a JavaScript class, there were still problems with cross domain requests with PhoneGap on WP8.

To achieve cross domain requests on WP8, I used XMLHttpRequests(Could also use JSONP, but this also supports other formats). This is the wrapper class that I ended up using:

```
(function() {
    name.of.package.HTTPRequest = function(destination, success, error, contentType) {
        var STATUS_IDLE = 0;
        var STATUS_OPEN = 1;
        var STATUS_LOADED = 2;
        var STATUS_WORKING = 3;
        var STATUS_DONE = 4;

        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open('GET', destination, true);

        if(contentType) {
            req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", contentType);
        }
        else {
            req.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
        }

        req.onreadystatechange = function(aEvt) {
            if(req.readyState == STATUS_DONE) {
                if(req.status == 200) {
                    if(success) {
                        success(req.responseText);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if(error) {
                        error("Response returned with error code: " + req.status);
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        req.send(null);
    };
}) ();
```